# What is the Chinese word for "home office"?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the correct Chinese term for "home office"? 办公室 is an office in an office building, and would not be correct.

Comment: what `home office' do you mean? If you are referring to a government department of the UK, that would be 内政部 or 内务部...

Comment: Have you tried [Google](http://translate.google.com/#en/zh-CN/home%20office)? 在家办公 or 家庭办公室

Comment: I mean "home office" as in working from an office in my own home. GOOGLE and other search engines offers all sorts of translations, however I am looking for a term that is being used in China.

Answer (score 5):

**SOHO** (small office/home office) is a new business *concept* that encompasses the idea of working and living, flexibility and connectivity using the limited space of a small office or home office. Depending on local regulation, real estate developments that are being marketed as SOHO may or may not be approved for both office *and* residential use.

The proper term to describe SOHO activity is [居家就业](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%85%E5%AE%B6%E5%B0%B1%E6%A5%AD) or [家居办公](http://baike.baidu.com/view/4731.htm?fromId=289196). As for the translation of the term "home office", I would definitely go with **家居办公室**.

Comment: FYI Soho is not a commonly used term for home offices in my experience (in the US). When I hear "soho", I think [SoHo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoHo). It seems there are some English acronyms that are used more widely in Chinese than in English?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete That's right. SOHO carries its literal meaning in Chinese instead of referring to the district in NYC.

Answer (score 4):

I think `soho一族` or `在家办公` is  proper for this situation.

`家居办公` is not good, because 家居 is confusing in Chinese. You know, `家居` is also used in business.